# How to sort a hash table with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to sort my data as a *timeline*:

```
[
  {
    "date": "1996-07-16T08:26:01 -02:00",
    "isPublished": false,
    "events": [
      {
        "title": "occaecat aliqua dolor sint",
        "text": "Laboris nisi dolor ipsum pariatur veniam esse.",
        "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
        "isPublished": true,
        "tags": [
          "elit",
          "incididunt",
          "consectetur"
        ]
      },
      ...
  },
  {
    "date": "1989-09-27T01:46:10 -01:00",
    "isPublished": false,
    "events": [
      {
        "title": "reprehenderit excepteur id minim",
        "text": "Commodo id officia est irure proident duis. Occaecat",
        "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
        "isPublished": false,
        "tags": [
          "ex",
          "occaecat",
          "commodo"
        ]
      },
      ..
  }
]
```

After reading some answers here on SO, I came with this so far:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  require 'httparty'
  def index
    response = HTTParty.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/valterhenrique/timeliner-sample/master/sample-data.json')
    @dates = JSON.parse(response.body)
    @sorted_dates = @dates.sort_by {|s| Date.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d')}
    puts @new_dates
  end
  ...
end
```

But I had no success so far. Any idea of how to sort these data by date ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@dates.sort_by { |s| Date.parse(s["date"]) }
```

The above will produce a `Date` instance out of the string, that is stored under `"date"` key in each subsequent hash.

As @yzalavin properly noted in comments, you might want to instantiate `DateTime` to make the sorting better:

```
@dates.sort_by { |s| DateTime.parse(s["date"]) }
```

Comment: Maybe `DateTime`?

Comment: @yzalavin indeed, thanks, I just copied what was in the OP.

Comment: WOW! Thank you sir! The Ruby community is really amazing! I'm new to RoR, and hope to repay your help soon, good sir!